# Decision between storing lookup table id's or pure data

Tags: sql, database, lookup, database-normalization

I find this comes up a lot, and I'm not sure the best way to approach it.

**The question I have is how to make the decision between using foreign keys to lookup tables, or using lookup table values directly in the tables requesting it, avoiding the lookup table relationship completely.**

Points to keep in mind:

- With the second method you would
  need to do mass updates to all
  records referencing the data if it
  is changed in the lookup table.
- This is focused more
  towards tables that have a lot of
  the column's referencing many lookup
  tables.Therefore lots of foreign
  keys means a lot of
  joins every time you query the
  table.
- This data would be coming from drop
  down lists which would be pulled
  from the lookup tables. In order to match up data when reloading, the values need to be in the existing list (*related to the first point*).

Is there a best practice here, or any key points to consider?

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  Perhaps you could reword or clarify?

Comment: This is not normalization. (But there is a common misconception that it is.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use a lookup table with a VARCHAR primary key, and your main data table uses a FOREIGN KEY on its column, with cascading updates.

```
CREATE TABLE ColorLookup (
  color VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE ItemsWithColors (
  ...other columns...,
  color VARCHAR(20),
  FOREIGN KEY (color) REFERENCES ColorLookup(color)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

This solution has the following advantages:

- You can query the color names in the main data table without requiring a join to the lookup table.
- Nevertheless, color names are constrained to the set of colors in the lookup table.
- You can get a list of unique colors names (even if none are currently in use in the main data) by querying the lookup table.
- If you change a color in the lookup table, the change automatically cascades to all referencing rows in the main data table.

---

It's surprising to me that so many other people on this thread seem to have mistaken ideas of what "normalization" is.  Using a surrogate keys (the ubiquitous "id") has nothing to do with normalization!

---

Re comment from @MacGruber:

Yes, the size is a factor. In InnoDB for example, every secondary index stores the primary key value of the row(s) where a given index value occurs. So the more secondary indexes you have, the greater the overhead for using a "bulky" data type for the primary key.

Also this affects foreign keys; the foreign key column must be the same data type as the primary key it references. You might have a small lookup table so you think the primary key size in a 50-row table doesn't matter. But that lookup table might be referenced by millions or *billions* of rows in other tables!

There's no right answer for all cases. Any answer can be correct for different cases. You just learn about the tradeoffs, and try to make an informed decision on a case by case basis.

Comment: If there wasn't an extra table for colors, what level of normal form would it be breaking? (3rd, 4th, etc)

Comment: @MobileMon, You misunderstand the purpose of normalization. It's not about making more tables. Normal forms are about representing data without redundancy. 

The lookup table of colors in my example doesn't have anything to do with the normal forms of the ItemsWithColors table. It's about creating a constraint so that the varchar is limited to a finite list of specific strings (color names). This helps to define the domain of the `color` column, but it doesn't really help or hinder the goal of eliminating redundancy.

Comment: I believe it violates 6th normal form https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form

Comment: @MobileMon, that would require that the ItemsWith Colors table above has at least one non-trivial join dependency. That would imply that besides `color`, there's another column that is not part of the candidate key. The example only lists "...other columns..." as a placeholder, which might be only the columns of the candidate key. So there's not enough information to judge whether the table is in 6NF.

Comment: Does the size of the lookup column factor into the decision to use an ID column or not?  If you have a varchar(64) or varchar(256) vs. an integer ID column, wouldn't that use a lot more storage space?  I suppose if space isn't an issue or the difference is trivial then skipping the ID column is a no brainer.  Just for the record, I like the idea of not using an ID column.  I created a lookup table without one then second-guessed that decision which lead me to this thread.  Glad to find my intuition confirmed!

Comment: @BillKarwin if ever you have to change a row in lookup table, how would you do that? considering the fact that it would be a primary key in the table.

Comment: @WAQ It's more common to INSERT a new value to a lookup table. But if you need to UPDATE a value, you can use a cascading foreign key constraint to automatically update dependent rows. The example I gave above shows the syntax `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. Try it out!

Comment: @BillKarwin that's true and it works. But most DBs don't let you (or encourage) you to change primary key values lets say I'm using Entity Framework, that would not let you change the primary key of the table unless I use a stored procedure and update through it.

Comment: @WAQ That's a pity, because it's exactly the reason that cascading foreign key constraints exist. It's a normal operation in SQL. But cascading updates must be atomic, so it must be executed internally in the RDBMS, it can't be "simulated" by a framework. That's why the developers of a framework would believe that it's a bad practice. In that case, you can't use the solution I show above in EF.

Answer (score 5):

In cases of simple atomic values, I tend to disagree with the common wisdom on this one, mainly on the complexity front. Consider a table containing hats. You can do the "denormalized" way:

```
CREATE TABLE Hat (
  hat_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  brand VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  size INT NOT NULL,
  color VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL /* color is a string, like "Red", "Blue" */
)
```

Or you can normalize it more by making a "color" table:

```
CREATE TABLE Color (
  color_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  color_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Hat (
  hat_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  brand VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  size INT NOT NULL,
  color_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Color(color_id)
)
```

The end result of the latter is that you've added some complexity - instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM Hat
```

You now have to say:

```
SELECT * FROM Hat H INNER JOIN Color C ON H.color_id = C.color_id
```

Is that extra join a huge deal? No - in fact, that's the foundation of the relational design model - normalizing allows you to prevent possible inconsistencies in the data. But every situation like this adds a *little bit* of complexity, and unless there's a good reason, it's worth asking why you're doing it. I consider possible "good reasons" to include:

- **Are there other attributes that "hang off of" this attribute?** Are you capturing, say, both "color name" and "hex value", such that hex value is always dependent on color name? If so, then you definitely want a separate color table, to prevent situations where one row has ("Red", "#FF0000") and another has ("Red", "#FF3333"). Multiple correlated attributes are the #1 signal that an entity should be normalized.
- **Will the set of possible values change frequently?** Using a normalized lookup table will make future changes to the elements of the set easier, because you're just updating a single row. If it's infrequent, though, don't balk at statements that have to update lots of rows in the main table instead; databases are quite good at that. Do some speed tests if you're not sure.
- **Will the set of possible values be directly administered by the users?** I.e. is there a screen where they can add / remove / reorder the elements in the list? If so, a separate table is a must, obviously.
- **Will the list of distinct values power some UI element?** E.g. is "color" a droplist in the UI? Then you'll be better off having it in its own table, rather than doing a SELECT DISTINCT on the table every time you need to show the droplist.

If none of those apply, I'd be hard pressed to find another (good) reason to normalize. If you just want to make sure that the value is one of a certain (small) set of legal values, you're better off using a CONSTRAINT that says the value must be in a specific list; keeps things simple, and you can always "upgrade" to a separate table later if the need arises.

Comment: ummm, in this case, you could have hat.color have a foreign key on color.color. Normalization != creating fake keys. Also, you've basically said that there is no need to move color to its own table if it has no meaning; it is just a arbitrary string.... well, yeah. It isn't a relation then.

Comment: @derobert - Agreed, it's not a relation if it's just arbitrary strings. I took that to be the thrust of his question: when do you make it a relation, and when do you not?

Answer (score 3):

One thing no one has considered is that you would not join to the lookup table if the data in it can change over time and the records joined to are historical. The example is a parts table and an order table. The vendors may drop parts or change part numbers, but the orders table should alawys have exactly what was ordered at the time it was ordered. Therefore, it should lookup the data to do the record insert but should never join to the lookup table to get information about an existing order. Instead the part number and description and price, etc. should be stored in the orders table. This is espceially critical so that price changes do not propagate through historical data and make your financial records inaccurate. In this case, you would also want to avoid using any kind of cascading update as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can even make it a rule to always program against the views, having the view get the lookups.

This makes it possible to optimize the view and make your code resistant to changes in the tables.

In oracle, you could even convert the view into a materialized view if you ever need to.

Comment: Materialized views are not Oracle-specific. SQL Server supports indexed views which are basically the same thing, though the syntax is different.

Answer (score 2):

rauhr.myopenid.com [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383026/decision-between-storing-lookup-table-ids-or-pure-data#383580):

> The way we decided to solve this problem is with 4th normal form. 
>   ...

That is not 4th normal form. That is a common mistake called One True Lookup:
http://www.dbazine.com/ofinterest/oi-articles/celko22

4th normal form is :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form

Comment: Joe Celko article is no longer there. Wayback machine suggests that https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/iB2pbubIAEU/AgLLI1d3MPUJ has the text of it, but not quite as pretty.

Comment: Replacing values by other values that are ids is not normalization.

Answer (score 1):

Normalization is pretty universally regarded as part of best practices in databases, and normalization says yeah, you push the data out and refer to it by key.

Comment: Only until it doesn't make sense any more. The norm is also to denormalize when performance suffers because of too normalized data. Sometimes a logical structure is just too slow.

Comment: I don't disagree.  The OP is asking in a pretty general way, though, so I'd tend to say "normalize" until I see that normalization is too much for the situation.

Comment: Replacing values by other values that are ids is not normalization.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one else has addressed your second point: When queries become long and difficult to read and write due to all those joins, a view will usually resolve that.

Comment: I always caution on the use of views - they save readability but they may have a significant performance cost.

Comment: Views are fairly cheap on most databases as they normally function by query rewriting. Check your DB's 'explain' (or similar) output, of course.