# Database design about list of constant strings

Tags: sql, database, database-design

For database design, if the value of a column is from a constant list of strings, such as `status`, `type`. Should I create a new table and have a foreign key or just store plain strings in the same table.

For example, I have a `orders` table with status:

```
----------------------------
| id | price | status      |
----------------------------
| 1  | 10.00 | pending     |
| 2  | 03.00 | in_progress |
| 3  | xx.xx | done        |
```

An alternative for above table is to have a `order_status` table and store `status_id` in orders table. I'm not sure if another table is necessary here.

Comment: In the case you described, I would store the plain strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decision between storing lookup table id's or pure data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383026/decision-between-storing-lookup-table-ids-or-pure-data)

Answer (score 1):

If it's more than just a few different values and/or values are frequently added you should go with a normalized data model, i.e. a table.

Otherwise you also might go for a column, but you need to add a `CHECK(status in ('pending','in_progress,'done'))` to avoid wrong data. This way you get the same consistency without the FK.

To save space you might use abbreviations (one or a few characters, e.g. `'p', 'i', 'd'`) but not meaningless numbers(`1,2,3`). Resolving the long values can be done in a View level using CASE.

ENUMs are proprietary, so IMHO better avoid it...

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to create a table just for static values.

Instead, you could use the ENUM type, which has a pre set value, as the example:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INT,
    price DOUBLE,
    status ENUM('pending', 'in progress', 'done')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are pros and cons for each solution and you need pick the best for your own project and you may have to switch later if the initial choice is bad.

In your case, storing status directly can be good enough. But if you want to prevent invalid status stored in your database, or you have a very long status text, you may want to store them separately with a foreign key constraint.

ENUM is another solution. However, if you need a new status later, you have to change your table definition, which can be a very bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

If the status has extra data associated with it, like display order or a colour, then you would need a separate table. Also, choosing pre-entered values from a table prevents semi-duplicate values (for example, one person might write "in progress" whereas another might write "in_progress" or "progressing") and aids in searching for orders with the same status.

I would go for a separate table as it allows more capabilities and lowers error.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `order_status` table with the literal as the primary key. Then in your `orders` table, cascade updates on the `status` column in case you modify the literals in the `order_status` table. This way you have data consistency and avoid join queries.

Comment: This question should be (flagged to be) voted closed as a duplicate. (An obvious & easily found one even when asked.) In the future please don't answer such questions, flag them. Moreover there is not enough information to decide between options, so there are more reasons to close & not answer. [ask] [answer] [help]

Comment: Thanks @philipxy, The link you posted, helped me. But i read the question and the answer twice to understand. Because i'm not English native. Maybe the questioner was like me or worse and not have understood the question well.