# DB Design: which relationship (One-To-Many or Many-To-Many) is best for this scenario?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, relational-database, one-to-many

Let me simplify this question.
Lets say that we have students and subjects.
Each Students can choose upto any 4 subjects.

**Type A  Design:**

Students table

```
id  Students_name
1   John
2   Jack
3   Jill
4   Nancy
```

Subjects table

```
id  Subjects    Students_id
1   Language      1
2   Maths        1
3   Science       1
4   History       1
5   Computer        2
6   Language      2
7   Maths        2
8   Science       2
9   History       3
10  Computer        3
11  Maths        3
12  Science       3
```

**Type B Design**

Same students table as type A

Subjects table

```
id  Subjects    
1   Language      
2   Maths       
3   Science       
4   History       
5   Computer
```

Another junction table is added here in this type as follows

students_subjects_mapping table

```
id  Subjects_id Students_id
1   1             1
2   2             1
3   3             1
4   4             1
5   5             2
6   2             2
7   3             2
8   4             2
```

So which type is better for this scenario?

Comment: Re "relationships": In the relational model *tables* represent application/business relationships/associations. FKs (foreign keys) get *called* relationships by methods/products/presentations that don't understand the relational model. FK declarations are not need to query or update a database. They just tell the DBMS that subrow values somewhere also have to appear somewhere else so it can prevent invalid states. PS Google 'stackoverflow philipxy database subtyping'.

Comment: You have called two tables that you have at the same time "Subjects" in design B. Suggest you call the student-subject association table something like Attends in both designs. And it's hard to imagine why you would need an id in those student-subject association tables. PS I happened to notice this question was edited without notifying either current commenter, I'll notify @citrusy.

Comment: This is now a faq duplicate, eg [Decision between storing lookup table id's or pure data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383026/3404097).

Comment: As I already said, you should change the A "Subjects" student-subject association table to the same name & the same student-subject pairs & use some name like Attends or Takes or Resgistration, not the meaningless "mapping"--what mapping? It maps a student to the subjects they take, and it maps a subject to the students that take it. "student-subject" says something about the relationship, but practically nothing. The relationship is, *attends* or *takes*. And it isn't *hates* or *is good at*--there's no *one* "mapping* or relationship/association between two things. So use a meaningful name.