# Use index or replace values by surrogate ids and add a separate table?

Tags: mysql, sql, normalization, database-normalization, surrogate-key

Currently I've got a couple of `pivot` tables with this structure in `mysql`:

**user_id | organisation_id | type**

```
4   3   external
4   3   internal
6   4   internal
7   4   external
6   5   external
7   5   external
7   6   internal
```

As you can see, in my `type` column I only use `external` and `internal`. Currently the `type` column is a `enum` and is indexed.

Is this a good database structure or should I make a separate table for the column `type`?

I've got this "problem" with a couple of tables so it's an important decision. The table could become quite big.

What would you do in this situation?

Comment: What does "make a separate table for the column type" mean? Please explain/illustrate. Do you mean, replace type values by surrogate ids and have a table associating ids & type values?

Comment: @philipxy yes that's what I mean.

Comment: I already improved your title to say that. Please edit your question, comments are not for clarifications, they are ephemeral and for requesting & pinning down clarifications to be edited into posts. PS You need to be clear, precise and complete in questions. Applicable but vague descriptions/summaries of (parts of) what you are thinking of do not communicate what you are thinking of. Complete accompanying examples also help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decision between storing lookup table id's or pure data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383026/decision-between-storing-lookup-table-ids-or-pure-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends a great deal on the kind of queries that you are going to run against this table.

If you plan to run queries that *ignore* the `type` column, i.e. do not care if it's internal or external, or queries that decide what `type` they want at run-time, e.g. through user input, there is a great advantage to keeping everything in a single table.

Generally, indexing a column with poor selectivity, i.e. with roughly half the rows in each of its two categories, can deliver only marginal performance improvements compared to a full table scan. Same goes for splitting the table in two: it will make queries more complex with very little improvement.