# What are the pros and cons of associative table?

Tags: sql, rdbms

In RDBMS, I believe there are several ways to design a relationship between tables. Therefore, I would like to ask what are the **pros** and **cons** between creating a relationship **with associative table** and **without associative table**. Is there a formal solution to decide on both?

Using generic tables, below I demonstrate what I mean:

**Example #1 (Without associative table)**

users

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | James |
|  3 | Jacob |
+----+-------+
```

comments

```
+----+-----------------------------+---------+
| id |            text             | user_id |
+----+-----------------------------+---------+
|  1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. |       1 |
|  2 | Praesent ultricies libero.  |       2 |
|  3 | Donec eget blandit nunc.    |       3 |
+----+-----------------------------+---------+
```

Note: the reference to the comment author is stored in `comments`.

**Example #2 (With associative table)**

users

```
+----+-------+  
| id |  name |  
+----+-------+  
| 1  |  John |  
| 2  | James |  
| 3  | Jacob |  
+----+-------+
```

comments

```
+----+-----------------------------+  
| id |                        text |  
+----+-----------------------------+  
| 1  | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. |  
| 2  |  Praesent ultricies libero. |  
| 3  |    Donec eget blandit nunc. |  
+----+-----------------------------+
```

comment_user

```
+----+--------------+-----------+
| id | comment_id   | user_id   |
+----+--------------+-----------+
| 1  | 1            |        1  |
| 2  | 2            |        2  |
| 3  | 3            |        3  |  
+----+--------------+-----------+
```

Note: the reference to the comment author is stored in `comment_user`.

Comment: I'm not sure I would called what you've done a "pivot", if I'm understanding correctly that is more commonly called an associative entity and it's used to resolve many to many relationships.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a pivot table by any stretch of the imagination. Perhaps a "Relationship" table since you are storing the relationship between the comment and the user. I would say: If the relationship is 1:1 and if you aren't going to store any other attributes unique to the relationship object, than the relationship table is unnecessary. In this scenario, I would go with a two table option. The `user_id` is definitely an attribute of a `comment` and it's 1:1, furthermore there are no other attributes unique to that relationship that wouldn't also apply to the comment object.

Comment: I just corrected the term. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decision between storing lookup table id's or pure data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383026/decision-between-storing-lookup-table-ids-or-pure-data)

Comment: Hi. How could this not have been asked before? This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing formal, no.

Pros:

- Association tables can handle both one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships, depending on what keys you define.
- You can have Comments without Users (without using NULLs).
- Association tables can be added to an existing database without modifying the existing tables.

Cons:

- The extra table clutters up your schema a bit.
- An extra join when querying is a bit more complex, and may impact performance.
- Making sure that every Comment has a User (if that is a requirement) is more complicated.

As an aside, the id column in the comment_user table appears to be pointless.

Comment: being a primary key, the id column in the comment_user table doesn't improve the performance of querying a row?

Comment: No, probably not. If you define the id column as a key, your dbms will most likely create an index on it. This will speed up queries _that select rows based on id values_, e.g. `comment_user where id=3`. In your example, such queries are unlikely, since no other tables refer to the id column, and the id doesn't mean anything in and of itself. It is more likely that you would query (or join) the comment_user table on the comment_id and/or user_id columns, in which case an index on id won't help at all - and it will slow down inserts and updates.

Answer (score 8):

You are using the term "pivot table" incorrectly.  There are various terms for the intermediate table; common names include junction table and association table.  Pros and cons is also strange -- you are inviting opinion, which is explicitly not allowed on Stack Overflow.  But, your question is rather misguided.  As such, it is worthy of being answered.

Your two options do different things.  The first implements a 1:n relationship.  A given user can have many comments.  But a comment can only belong to a single user.

The second implements an m:n relationship.  A given user can have many comments.  A given comment can also have many users.

Obviously, a 1:n relationship can be implemented as a special case of an m:n relationship.  However that is overkill and inefficient.

The relationship between users and comments would typically be 1:n, so the first structure seems more natural for this purpose.

Comment: With "pros" and "cons" I mean: a formal solution on which occasions I will use the examples above. However, thanks for the corrections and suggestions.

Comment: @zaclummys: As Gordon says: there is no pros, no cons, but only appropriateness. For an m:n relation use a bridge table, for a 1:n relation don't. I suggest you accept this answer :-)

Comment: @IsaacFerreira . . . I find it curious that you unaccepted this answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The other answer fits better to my question.