# Separate tables for different types of constants or a single table?

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

In my project I have constants for multiple types, like 4 constants for platform type (type 1)(MAC, WIN, ANDROID, IOS), 4-5 constants for another type(type 2), 3-4 constants of another type (type 3) and so on. 
Should I make separate tables for different types of data, like one for platform, one for type 2 another for type 3 or should I make one single table with an extra column specifying the type of constant.

Comment: This isn't normalization. Also it's a faq. Google sql/database subtypes/inheritance/polymorphism.

Comment: Try searching for OTLT or "one true lookup table".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decision between storing lookup table id's or pure data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383026/decision-between-storing-lookup-table-ids-or-pure-data)

Answer (score 1):

You should have separate tables. Otherwise, from database perspective it would be acceptable to set type2=ANDROID and platform=Butterfly :)

Creating an extra table is not that much work, and things will be simpler that way. In particular, mapping constants on application level may become needlessly complicated if you have it all in one table.