# What's best practice for normalisation of DB where a domain table has an "Other" option for free text?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema, database-normalization

I'm normalising a database for my company and one pattern I'm seeing a lot is using a domain lookup table for a value but also allowing "Other" and storing the results in a separate column.

Is there a cleaner way of representing this?

I'm following the normal forms up to 5NF and domain key form. In some tables this pattern is repeated more than once so we have a table like the following:

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ appliance_id ║ location_type_id ║ other_location_type ║ appliance_type_id ║ other_appliance_type ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║          123 ║                1 ║ {null}              ║                13 ║ Freestanding Boiler  ║
║          124 ║               13 ║ Annex               ║                 1 ║ {null}               ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

Where for example, a location_type_id & appliance_type_id of 13 is "Other" in the relevant lookup tables.

So for example, the location type table looks something like this:

```
╔═════╦═══════════════╗
║ id  ║ location_type ║
╠═════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1   ║ Living Room   ║
║ 2   ║ Kitchen       ║
║ ... ║ ...           ║
║ 13  ║ Other         ║
╚═════╩═══════════════╝
```

This might very well be the best possible solution (although I would probably separate the location and appliance type into different tables).

Comment: One idea would be to move the Other columns to separate tables, which would eliminate the NULL column entries.  I'd do a text scan of the Other columns and make sure the lookup tables are as complete as possible.

Comment: Replacing values by other values that "identify" them is not either of the things that [tag:database-normalization] means--normalization to 1NF & to higher NFs. DKNF is not relevant to those either--it is not on the sequence to 5NF & 6NF. PS  Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decision between storing lookup table id's or pure data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383026/decision-between-storing-lookup-table-ids-or-pure-data)

Comment: Try to write the `SELECTs`.  I think that exercise will answer your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking it over, we're gonna do as suggested and do a text scan and use that to populate our lookups, then going forward we'll try to discourage the use of free-text fields for lookups, storing the values in a separate table for the time being so we don't clutter our main tables.