# Is it performance matters to separate select fields to separate table?

Tags: laravel, database-design

I have patients table 
It's contain smoking field it's values will be (smoker or non-smoker or ex-smoker)

My question is should I save values directly as string in patient table or make another table for smoking and make one-to-one relation between these tables?

Is it affects performance of query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decision between storing lookup table id's or pure data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383026/decision-between-storing-lookup-table-ids-or-pure-data)

Answer (score 0):

When I have three options like this, I typically use a nullable bit/bool. A bit/bool column will be more performant than a string column.

So, in your situation, my table would have a "smoking" column where null would be non-smoker, 0/false would be ex-smoker, and 1/true would be smoker.

If you think you might add options later, like maybe "recently quit" or something, a nullable bool might not be ideal as you'd have to alter the column, then write a script to convert all of them into the appropriate string.

If you don't want to use the nullable bool, then you'd want a one to many table where you listed each option: "smoker, non-smoker, ex-smoker" then add a foreign key onto the "smoking" table in your patients table. That would also increase performance over throwing strings in the column.