# Should I create a separate table in MySQL when I have fixed number of possible values for a field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-connection, relational-database

I'm doing some database optimization and I was wandering, if I have a table `Users`, and that table has a `_status` field, should I be creating a separate table for status codes like so:

```
Table statuses:
    _status_id: PK int(16) Ai,
    _status_name: varchar(32)
```

and then have a `status_code_id` field in the `Users` table that links to the `_status_id` field of the `statuses` table, or just write the _status_name directly in the User?

I should note that there are fixed number of statuses, and i do not plan to add any additional data regarding the status like status description or status code or something like that. Its always going to be 4 statuses - active, inactive, away, busy.

I think that if im doing some sort of `get by status query`, it will take longer if they are separated into 2 tables then it would if it was all in one table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decision between storing lookup table id's or pure data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383026/decision-between-storing-lookup-table-ids-or-pure-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends from the case:

Does this `status` is important in your application? Is it used in many logics? Then it should have a separate table, as it will reduce the hardcoding in the application.

On a theoretical level also should be a separate table, as it represents a well defined entity. (IMHO)

Comment: Yes, it is correct to separate them if we look at it from a technical point. Im not sure it is the same if we look at it from a practical point. 
Ive decided to keep them separated for the purpose of scalability - if i decide to add another status code or additional fields in the status table in the future.
Thanks for the answer, cheers!

Comment: Another table will have no scalability issue, also, will be easier to maintain, for example if you wish to change one of the  status' name. 
The only valid reason i can think to don't create another table is the initial developing cost (SQL, queries) and initial data entry. On an efficiency point of view you will gain speed when doing query on the status as it will be a foreign key