# Many-to-many relationship without intersection table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, database-normalization

I am setting up a database where I'd like to have many-to-many relationships between some tables. There's no user interface for this database; we will be putting data into the tables using R scripts and retrieving it using Python scripts.

The entities involved are projects and cost forecasts. Multiple projects may use the same forecast. For each forecast, there are costs to develop a project in each of several future years. I need to be able to retrieve the cost forecast for each future year for each individual project.

I think the tables below would be a fairly standard way to represent these relationships. Note that "pk" means "primary key" and "fk" means "foreign key".

```
PROJECT
  name
  forecast_id (fk)

FORECAST
  forecast_id (pk)

COST
  forecast_id (fk)
  year
  cost
```

To retrieve the forecast for a particular project, I would just retrieve all the rows from `COST` that have a matching `forecast_id`. I don't need the `FORECAST` table for anything, except as a home for the `forecast_id` that establishes the many-to-many relationship between `PROJECT` and `COST`.

So my main question is, can I just drop the `FORECAST` table and have a direct many-to-many relationship between `PROJECT` and `COST`, using the `forecast_id`? I know this is physically possible, but many discussions use language along the lines that "many-to-many relationships aren't possible without a bridge table." But why would I want to add the bridge table, if I can do all my queries without it and it is one more table I would have to maintain?

Going further, many discussions of many-to-many relationships (including @mike-organek's comment below) suggest a structure similar to this:

```
PROJECT
  project_id (pk)
  name

PROJECT_COST
  project_id (fk)
  cost_id (fk)

COST
  cost_id (pk)
  year
  cost
```

While this seems like a commonly preferred approach, it suits my needs even less well. Now every time I add a new project, instead of just assigning the `forecast_id` corresponding to a particular forecast, I have to add a bunch of link records to the PROJECT_COST table, one for each future year. This will also require a lot of management, and allows potential creation of relationships I don't want (e.g., one project uses costs from one forecast for the first two years, then costs from a different forecast for the next two years).

So my second question is, is there anything preferable about the second approach over the first approach, or over my simplified approach (using just the PROJECT and COST tables)?

**Update**

There seems to be some confusion about what I'm asking here. So I've revised the question significantly to try to make it clearer. Note that I renamed `cost_group` to `forecast` as part of this.

Comment: How does this make your life worse?  Do projects span years?  If so, then you have to have a many-to-many join table between `project` and `project_cost`.  Having that link happens to also give you the ability to share forecasts (by year) between projects.  Do you have a better alternative in mind?

Comment: Yes, each project may have multiple matching rows in the COST table (i.e., forecasts for multiple future years). I'm not sure which normalization you're asking about, but both make my life worse, since they include extra tables that I have to create and keep consistent. Why shouldn't I just implement a direct many-to-many relationship between the foreign keys in PROJECT and COST, as shown in the first example? (Sort of equivalent to having a phantom COST_GROUP table that I never bother to create.)

Comment: Am I reading this wrong?  Projects span years.  In a given year, a project is associated with a cost_group.  Cost_group for a given year has a cost value.  If this is true, then you should have tables for Project, Year, Cost_group as your independent entities.  A project_year join table establishes that a Project is valid within a Year.  A cost_group_year join table establishes the cost value for a cost_group for a year.  A join table (project_year_cost) for project_year to cost_group_year completes your model that associates what cost model a particular project uses in a particular year.

Comment: The `cost_group`s could be something like "coal" or "gas". For each project, the `cost_group` is the same for all years. For some projects, I would use the cost forecast for `cost_group = "coal"`, which has values for 2020, 2025, 2030, etc. And for other projects, I would use `cost_group = "gas"`, which also has values for different years. I can implement this many-to-many relation just by creating the two tables shown in the first example. Why would I want to create any additional tables? (In particular, I don't want to allow mixing "coal" and "gas" cost forecasts for the same project.)

Comment: Follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Dozens of published academic information modelling & DB design textbooks are online free in pdf. (But asking for resources outside SO is off-topic.) Right now this asks us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial. Follow one & ask 1 clear specific non-duplicate question about where you are 1st stuck.

Comment: The 2nd records groups with no projects and/or costs, which the 1st can't. Adding ids doesn't change what can be represented (presuming 1:1 correspondence between ids & things). So the 3rd records what the 2nd does. PS We can expect consise phrasings of your questions to be faqs. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decision between storing lookup table id's or pure data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383026/decision-between-storing-lookup-table-ids-or-pure-data)

Comment: @philipxy Thanks for your advice. The other question kind of goes in a different direction from mine, and I'm hoping for something more specific than "read a textbook on data normalization." I think my question boils down to "can I drop a linking table if it holds no useful data in its own right? If not, why shouldn't I?" I've revised the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second approach (with the `project_cost` table containing two foreign keys) is the correct way to model a many-to-many relationship.

But your idea with the shared `forecast_id` (with or without `forecast` table) exhibits that you are not thinking of a many-to-many relationship in the ordinary sense: if one `project` is associated with a certain set of `cost`s, all other `project`s must either be associated with the same or a disjoint set of `cost`s.

If that is what you want, I see no problem with removing the `forecast` table. There is no referential integrity you are losing that way.

If you have additional requirements, for example that there has to be at least a `cost` and a `project` for each existing `forecast_id`, things may change. That could be guaranteed with foreign keys *from* the `forecast` table, but not without that table.